# Sharing folders over LAN while dialing pppoe through router on windows

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing, pppoe

I can't seem to get this working. I'd like to have folders shared on the LAN while I have one or more PPPoE connections dialed through the DSL router. The shares are visible if I have no pppoe connections dialed and rely on the main connection dialed by the router. If I dial a pppoe connection my PC becomes hidden to the LAN.

The operating system is Windows 7.

Comment: It helps if you draw us a picture of your LAN.  How are all your computers connected?  Are they all connected through your router?  A separate switch?

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of your base network with and without pppoe? Home or Public? OS will sometimes change your network type when you use pppoe.